# Fetching documents in xquery

Tags: xquery

I need to fetch documents from DB in xquery between dates [from date and to date].
From Date - 30 days before from Current Date
To Date - current date

In every document, I have an attribute named "loadDate". I have to fetch without creating an index for this attribute. Is that possible?

Please help.

Thanks,
-N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your 'loadDate' attribute has type xs:date, and making up an imaginary structure for your documents, it sounds as if your query is simply:

```
/myns:doc
  [@loadDate gt (current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D'))]
```

Such a query might be slower without an index, but why would it not be possible?  In a declarative query language, the general principle is that the existence of an index should not change the meaning of any query, only the speed with which it can be evaluated.